# Плагин для интернет-магазина на WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Я хочу создать плагин для интернет-магазина построенного на базе WooCommerce.

Допустим, я хочу чтобы в списке товаров, те товары которых нет в наличии просто были с opacity 0.5 (я просто хочу сам потренироваться в создании плагина), я не понимаю какой хук я должен использовать. Вот на сайте WooCommerce есть список хуков: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html но где их описания? что я должен понимать из названия их? Ладно, допустим из woocommerce_cart_item_price     этого названия я могу понять к чему он относится, но многие просто неясны для меня. Я ожидал увидеть допустим хук, а при нажатии на него, чтобы выводилось описание хука. Гуглил, так и не нашел информации, прошу подсказать мне, как мне понять как называется хук, который отвечает за, допустим, вывод цены товара на странице?

Еще интересует вопрос, почему когда я меняю код своего плагина, то плагин обновляется не сразу при обновлении странички и нажатии кнопки F5? А только когда я перезайду в аккаунт.

P.S. У меня вышло сделать мини-плагин, который выводит на странице со всеми товарами "Товар закончен", тут я использовал хук woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title, но как бы я понял что он отвечает именно за это?